# How does fully create an internal release on Google Play Console via API?

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I am automating the creation of internal app release using the Google Play Console Developer API.

I can make the API creating a *draft* release for my *draft* app by:

1. [Create a new edit](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits/insert)
2. [Upload a bundle to the edit](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.bundles/upload)
3. [Update the track for the edit to be "internal" with status of "draft"](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks/update)
4. [Commit the edit against my package](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits/commit)

**However**, I still need to go into the UI and manually click `Edit release`" then `Next`, then `Save` to get an internal release to send to people

What extra steps am I missing from my Api calls to get to fully automate this process, please?

[image]

Comment: Would love to know why this was downvoted - I suppose a comment would have at least allowed me to improve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it turns out the reason why I could only create a draft release via the API was that I had not promoted a single release to another track.

When I *manually* promoted the internal release to "**closed alpha**" (which required me to add all the icons and screenshots etc.), then the API magically starts to allow me to set the status to be "**completed**" for the "**internal**" track, which it only previously allowed me to do via the UI by editing and saving the "**draft**" release created via the API.

I'm sure there’s method behind Google's madness on this one but it sure did confuse me!

Comment: Yeah, this API is terrible.